# CCParticle Meteor cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, ccparticlesystem

I have gone through the CCParticle's but the only problem I currently have is understanding what the items like startSize, endSize, startSizeVar, startColor and etc mean. Is there a link of what they all do or can someone explain to me?

Comment: i refer this link you can beter understand CCParticle's. http://pocketworx.com/?p=147

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **startSize** - is the size of the particle, when it appears (it's a quad, so only one number needed)
- **endsize** - is the size, when it will disappear - it will grow or shrink to this size through it's life period
- **startSizeVar** - is the start size variance - when it's not zero, the particle will appear at size: startSize +/- random number between 0 and startSizeVar
- **endSizeVar** - is the end size variance - when it's not zero, the particle will disappear at size: endSize +/- random number between 0 and endSizeVar
- **startColor** - the color of the partile, when appears
- **endColor** - the color of the particle when disappears (it's color will change during lifetime from startColor to endColor)

All of these properties are quite good explained in *CCParticleSystem.h* (by comments)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to the Cocos2d particles programming guide:

[Particles Programming Guide](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3aparticles)